# Populate Kendo UI Web Treeview from External Data Source - Retrieving data and Populate the treeview

Tags: .net, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I tried using ComponentOne Wijmo TreeView and Kendo UI Treeview. I have found many examples on Kendo TreeView however, I am unable to achieve something similar as Wijmo TreeView ( Please check the link below)
http://wijmo.com/populate-wijtree-from-external-data-source-using-knockout/

I am unable to figure out on how to proceed with such a scenario. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the closest you have come? Can you post the code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to remote service is demonstrated in the [binding to remote data](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/remote-data.html) demo.